# jQuery: Check if character is in string

Tags: jquery, variables

I want the simplest way to check if an underscore (_) is in a variable using jQuery and do something if is not..

```
if ( '_ is not in var') {
   // Do
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
var str = "i am a string with _";
if (str.indexOf('_') == -1) {
   // will not be triggered because str has _..
}
```

and as spender said below on comment, jQuery is not a requirement..
[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) is a native javascript

Comment: It's probably important to highlight to OP that the solution does not require jQuery, as demonstrated.

Comment: Its worth noting that this isn't jQuery but basic javascript so could be used even without jQuery being loaded. The answer is correct of course, just a noteworthy addition given the question.

Answer (score 14):

There are several ways to do this.

1. `indexOf()` method:

   ```
   if( str.indexOf('_') != -1 ){
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do something 
   }
   ```
2. `Search()` method:

   ```
    if( str.search("_")!=-1 ){
      //do something
    } 
    else {
     //Do something 
    }
   ```
3. `:contains()` selector:

   ```
    if( $("p:contains(_)") ).length{
      //Do something
    }
    else{
      //Do something
    }
   ```
4. using a regular expression:

   ```
    if( str.match(/_/g) ).length{
      //Do something
    }
    else{
      //Do something
    }
   ```

I think the first method is the simplest way.